# Why would Windows 10 workstation give "Connecting" popup when saving file to network?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, network-share, windows-10, internal-dns

We have our main file server "Files" on a Windows 2012 R2 server which works fine for nearly every workstation. A couple however, both of which are Windows 10, are having an issue when saving to network shares:

After clicking Save As and then clicking on one of the recent file locations a small popup appears lasting anywhere from 5-30 seconds:

[Connecting - Trying to connect to: \files\example...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPFgg.png)

This does not occur when working directly with the server IP so I assumed it was a DNS issue. I've so far flushed the DNS cache and even tried adding the server to the workstation's hosts file however the issue persists. Ping resolved the IP correctly and returns <1ms.

The workstation is mostly used for Excel however popup has been seen in non-Office apps as well.

I've tried searching online for other potential solutions and not finding; perhaps using wrong search terms? I'd much appreciate any help diagnosing why these stations are having this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the Webclient.exe in services.msc on a client machine this is the workaround we've been given for now, other than that we too have the same issue and it seems to impact some users only and intermittently, we've logged tickets with our VPN vendor, Netapp and now have an open ticket with Microsoft, do you have any solutions we get the exact same issue?

Comment: Sorry I've since changed jobs and no longer have a system with this issue for testing. We never did find a solution while I was there.